# npm start does not work in angular 5 anymore

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, angular5

I'm trying to run npm start for angular 5 and I get the following error

> TypeError: callbacks[i] is not a function

Does anyone know where this comes from? It just appeared out of nowhere... There seems nothing to be wrong with my project (code)

Comment: same issue here

Answer (score 2):

Temporary fix:

Rollback the bugged dependency.

`npm install copy-webpack-plugin@4.3.0`

More info here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9550

Comment: You gotta be kidding me right. how can this happen?

Comment: I'm not kidding :P, it works, just make sure to use npm and not yarn. That's what happen when you use almost 1k dependencies. That's also why many are locked to a specific version. I guess.

Comment: apparently moving favicon.icon solves the problem, did anyone try that?

Comment: I removed the favicon in my project and I had the issue so I doubt.

Comment: @eugen_sunic Please don't forget to accept the answer if it fits your needs.