# Node Error on start (ng serve) Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

Angular Cli 1.6.8

Angular CDK 5.2.0

On NG Serve / npm start i get the following error

```
TypeError: callbacks[i] is not a function
    at Storage.finished (D:\USER\Test\AESWebPortal\aes-web-portal\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:40:15)
    at D:\USER\Test\AESWebPortal\aes-web-portal\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:77:9
    at D:\USER\Test\AESWebPortal\aes-web-portal\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:287:18
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:167:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! aes-web-portal@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the aes-web-portal@0.0.0 start script.
```

All this after updating to nodejs 9.5.0 (tried 8.x LTS as well) - upgraded from 6.x

NPM Version - 5.6.0

Any of you had this issue?

Comment: cf 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48686688/npm-start-does-not-work-in-angular-5-anymore

Comment: Thanks, that was the 'fix'